# Convert image to 3D .stl image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, 3d

I want to develop a software program that does the following

```
1.a person takes a picture of an object
2. add the picture to a software program that will convert the single picture into a 3d picture.
3. this picture then must be converted into a .stl file to print it as a 3d object.
```

I want to achieve these functionalists using HTML5 and css . please named me the plugin which i should use to convert images into 3d .also is it possible to covert images into .stl ???

Comment: It is not possible to accurately convert a 2D image into a 3D image. You would need 2D images from multiple vantage points to create an accurate 3D image.

Comment: ya i got to know this .... it is very old question ,but thanx for answer